# Show that $v(t) = \int_0^1 e^{\sqrt{x^2+t^2}} d\lambda$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to show that the function

$v(t) = \int_0^1  e^{\sqrt{x^2+t^2}} d\lambda$

(with $\lambda$ being the Lebesgue measure) is continuous for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. I've however hit a little snag.

I'm trying to show that $v(t)$ satisfies the continuity lemma, that is, that:

- $ x \mapsto e^{\sqrt{x^2+t^2}} \in \mathcal{L}^1([0,1],\lambda)$ for every fixed $t$
- $t \mapsto e^{\sqrt{x^2+t^2}}$ is continuous for every fixed $x$.
- $|e^{\sqrt{x^2+t^2}}| \leq w(x)$ for all $(t,x) \in \mathbb{R} \times [0,1]$ some $w(x) \in \mathcal{L}^1$

One and two I've done, and I'm pretty confident they're alright. It's number three that's giving me trouble - I'm completely stuck. Anyone got any tips/help?

Much appreciated! :-)

Comment: You should work locally: prove your third property for only $(t,x) \in [-M,M] \times [0,1]$, use that to conclude continuity on $[-M,M]$, and then conclude that you have continuity everywhere.

Comment: Hm, so

$|e^{\sqrt{x^2+t^2}}| \leq e^{\sqrt{x^2+M^2}} \leq e^{x^2+M^2+1} = e^1 e^{M^2} e^{x^2} \in \mathcal{L}^1([0,1],\lambda) $ for $(t,x) \in [-M,M] \times [0,1]$?

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, it's just really abstract! I'm having a hard time getting it :)

Comment: Sure, that should do the job.

Comment: Alright, thanks a bunch!